# To show how many times user has run the script

Tags: python

```
i = 
print("You have run the code {} times".format(i))
```

here I want to iterate the i value as many times user is running the code using python

So, after 1st time running
output looks like

```
You have run the code 1 times
```

after 2nd time running

```
You have run the code 2 times
```

Comment: Store the data on some database.

Comment: you can also use `json` or `yaml`

Comment: store i in a file. once script is loaded get the value in file and update it

Comment: Or also use a classic text file (.txt), there you can see some documentation on how to works with file on python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by 'run the code'.

1. If you mean how many times the code has been run while the program is alive (i.e. it resets every time the program exits) you can do:

```py
count = 0

def code_to_run():
  print("Running code")
  global count
  count +=1

while True:
  print("You have run the code {} times".format(count))
  run = str(input("Shall I run the code? (y/n) "))
  if run == "y":
    code_to_run()
  else:
    break
```

2. If you want the count to continue across multiple sessions and not reset on program exit:

```py
def get_count():
  count = 0
  try:
    with open("count.txt", "r") as file:
      count = int(file.read())
  finally:
    return count

def write_count(count):
  with open("count.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(count)


count = get_count()

def code_to_run():
  print("Running code")
  global count
  count +=1


while True:
  print("You have run the code {} times".format(count))
  run = str(input("Shall I run the code? (y/n) "))
  if run == "y":
    code_to_run()
  else:
    break

write_count(str(count))
```

Note: in the current code the updated count won't be written if the user exits the program with `ctrl + c`. You'll have to edit the code to handle that case (maybe write the count after each run?)

Comment: I want to reset every time the program exits. but is there any option that I don't want to write y every time. If I am running the code, it should automatic count

Comment: The "y" is just there to trigger the code run -- you can run it automatically without asking the user if you want. That's totally up to you. Without knowing more about your project, I can't really suggest an alternative

Comment: how can I run without asking the user?