# How to keep track of the number of runs of an R script per day

Tags: r, try-catch

I am currently looking to write a function in R that can keep track of the number of completed runs of an `.R` file within any particular day. Notice that the runs might be conducted at different time periods of a day. I did some research on this problem and came across this post ([To show how many times user has run the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692472/to-show-how-many-times-user-has-run-the-script)). So far I am unable to build upon the first commenter's code when converting into `R` (the main obstacle is to replicate the `try....except` ). However, I need to add the restriction that the count is measured only within a day (exactly from 00:00:00 AM EST to 24:00:00 AM EST).

Can someone please offer some help on how to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Either I didn't get the problem, or it seems a rather easy one: create a temporary file (use `Sys.Date()` to name it) and store the current run number there; at the beginning of your .R file, read the temporary file, increment the number, write the file back.

Comment: Thank you. I would need that count number to be included in certain file name as well. How do we remove that temporary file though? Like after a particular day passed, the file needs to be deleted automatically and new temporary file with count being reset would be needed.

Comment: Also, I guess an `IF ELSE` condition would be needed in order to reset the count number on the new day?

Comment: Yeah. Files are removed with `unlink()`

Comment: Since the `R script` can give several output files depending on the number of users' inputs, and each output file shares the common conventional naming pattern: `[Job ID]_Date1_Date2_Sys.Date()`, do you know how to add the number of runs X right before the JobID on *every* output files using only 1 `.txt` file?